# PHP curl not working, if i pass string as url than its working if i fetch url from db than curl returning error

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

working code

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://###.#####.###/####/####/T0103/templateCustomWebPage.do?webId=1209221452326&editCurrentLanguage=1209221452328&customWebPageId=1292822288140001019");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $data;[/code]
```

but if i use url from database than its not working.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $r->url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $data;
```

following error will be display...

```
parameter is wrong ,please check your input url.
Your input URL:
http://###.#####.###/####/####/T0103/templateCustomWebPage.do?webId=1209221452326&editCurrentLanguage=1209221452328&customWebPageId=1292822288140001019
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you post a `var_dump($r)`?

Comment: @MichaelDibbets yes i have tried, if i echo $r->url and copy that and put into first curl than its not working.

Comment: No, I mean post the results of `var_dump($r)` here so we can see what is actually inside `$r`

Comment: yes, but that doesn't tell us how $r is build up. `var_dump($r)` will tell us how `$r` is built up and then we can see if the issue might be there.
Right now all we have is your "word" that it works, but clearly it doesn't, hence your post.
That's why we need the full result that is outputted if you do `var_dump($r)`

Comment: @MichaelDibbets var_dump output 

object(stdClass)[25]
  public 'url_node_id' => string '5191' (length=4)
  public 'url' => string 'http://###.#####.###/####/####/T0103/templateCustomWebPage.do?webId=1209221452326&amp;editCurrentLanguage=1209221452328&amp;customWebPageId=1292822288140001019' (length=171)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your url is stored with html entities in the database. The CURL call doesn't accept those.

Try this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, html_entity_decode($r->url));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $data;
```

I've added **html_entity_decode** 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php